# LIbrary Routine Called out of Sequence Error

Tags: c, sqlite

Why can't I insert to my database? I've read multiple threads regarding this error and all of their problems were that they forgot calling open for the database. Help?

```
sqlite3 *data;
sqlite3_stmt *res;
char *errMSG;
int sql=0;
const char *tail;
char insert[100];

sql = sqlite3_open("pokemon.db", &data);
if(sql){
    puts("Can't open database");
    exit(0);
}

sprintf(insert, "Insert into Players values('%s','%s',1, 0,%d,%d,%d,0,0,'%s');", name, species, HP, ATTK, DEF, key);

sql = sqlite3_prepare_v2(data, insert, 1000, &res, &tail);
printf("%d\n",sql);
sqlite3_step(res);
sqlite3_finalize(res);
sqlite3_close(data);

printf("You have successfully captured a new Pokemon!<br>");
printf("%s", sqlite3_errmsg(data));
printf("<form action=start.cgi><input type=submit value='Go back to Home Page!'></form>");


printf("</body></html>");
return 0;
```

Comment: Why you are creating string SQL instead of parametrize ??? And waht is error number after insert?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean parametrize? Sql value is 0 after insert.
I'm really new to this, so I don't know much. Apologies. :(

Comment: Read this first : http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html, then this : http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html . You need to bind values to SQL parameters instead of creating SQL by yourself.Just a question, how are you sure that data was not inserted?

Comment: Thanks.
My other program prints all contents of the table, Players. Whenever I try running this one, the one's I entered using this code don't show up but the one's I entered directly through sqlite3 do.

Comment: @Nur-MikoGuiamano: you need to check the return values of all the sqlite3_* calls that return an error code. You shoudln't use sqlite3_errmsg if you don't know that the previous command failed. And yes, use prepared statements.

Comment: After transferring

sqlite3_step(res);
sqlite3_finalize(res);
sqlite3_close(data);

just before printf("</body></html>");

my return value for open and prepare are 0 and errmsg = not an error. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `sqlite3_errmsg(data)`, the database connection `data` has already been closed.

I suspect that this is invalid - and that this invalid call to `sqlite3_errmsg()` is what the error string refers to, rather than to any earlier error.